# Should a Linux Swap partition be on the RAID?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, swap

When setting up a new system, if I am planning on mirroring two hard drives, what should I do with the SWAP area? I can think of three things I can do...

1. Do a mirror of the SWAP partition
2. Stripe it for speed
3. Create two separate SWAP partitions

I can see number 1 just seeming "normal" compared to the rest of the partitions, but does it need to be mirrored? Would the system break if the Stripe (option 2) died? Would the system use both SWAP partitions if I created two separate ones? What would be the ideal setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/195839/where-should-my-swap-partition-s-live-when-using-software-raid1-performance-lv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap is memory, so if it died you'd probably get a kernel panic. At the very least, you'd see some binaries crash. That being said, if you don't need / want your system to keep running after a disk up and dies on you, go ahead and stripe because performance is king re:swap.

Comment: There'd be no point in having RAID-1 on the other partitions either if he doesn't need/want his system to keep running after a disk dies, seeing as to keep running after a disk dies is the sole point of RAID.

Comment: well, the comparison doesn't make sense. If he put swap on RAID0, then his process/system might crash, but he isn't really losing any data (leaving the one which is in RAM), but if he puts his system on RAID0, he will lose data and have to rebuilt the whole system from scratch.

Comment: raid-1 (mirror) makes sense for swap to get better reliability. yet, raid-0 (striping) for performance is not necessary because you can instead create something much simpler: two swap partitions (one for each drive) and Linux will "stripe" across as if it was raid-0: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Why_RAID%3F#Swapping_on_RAID

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk In many situations, putting the whole two disks into a RAID-1 and then the SWAP onto a partition / logical volume of that RAID-1 is easier to configure than to leave part of the disks un-RAID-ed. For example, HW raids often work on whole disks. But if one has already two partitions on two disks reserved for SWAP, it is indeed easier to `swapon` both of them instead of putting a RAID in between.